# VBA to copy cell value into another cell text string

Tags: vba, excel

I am managing inventory in Excel.
I have 2 columns to work with:

1. product name
2. packaging info

The table looks like this

```
product name             packaging info
BLISE FACEWASH           50GM
IVREA CREAM              60GM
IVREA CREAM              30GM
IVREA SHAMPOO            30ML
```

I want to add the value in packaging info into the product name,
but I want to add it before the last word in product name.

Desired result:

```
product name                 packaging info
BLISE 50GM FACEWASH          50GM
IVREA 60GM CREAM             60GM
IVREA 30GM CREAM             30GM
IVREA 30ML SHAMPOO           30ML
```

I tried concatenate but it does not help and makes it a lot more complicated.

I have been trying this with macros as it seems doable.

1. copy value in column 2
2. move to left cell
3. skip 1 word from right (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> arrow)
4. paste value
5. add a space
6. go to next row

All the cells in product name end up with same values. Where I am going wrong?

If not with macros, what would be the easiest way to do this?

By the way: the sheet contains 10 columns, 4500+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

VBA; Assumes headers are in A1/B1:

```
Sub MergeCols
    Dim cell As Range, pos As Long

    Set cell = Range("A2")

    Do Until cell.Value = ""
        pos = InStrRev(cell.Value, " ")
        If (pos > 0) Then
            cell.Value = Left$(cell.Value, pos) & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & Mid$(cell.Value, pos)
        Else
            cell.Value = cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: i am new to this stuff. can you help me in running the script. 
i created a macro. pasted the code in place. when i run it i get
compile error
invalid outside procedure.

Comment: works now. but not the exact result. it works perfect if the product name consists of just 2 words. if it is more, like 3 or 4 or 5 then the value pasted is not before the last word. it is somewhere in the middle
example
FOLICA 100ML HAIR TINCTURE SOLUTION
where as it should have been
FOLICA HAIR TINCTURE 100ML SOLUTION

Comment: For that just replace `InStr` with `InStrRev`

Comment: just PERFECT!!!!
thank you so much.
cant vote up the answer. 
thanks alot, especially for the quick answer and updates. you saved me alot of time.